# How to deploy and configure a remote clickhouse db instance with docker

Tags: database, clickhouse

I recently had to add clickhouse to our technology stack but unfortunately I didn't find any good, simple and fast tutorials for my needs and after some trial and error I could manage to do it by myself. To help others I decided to share my experience.

So how to deploy and configure a remote **ClickHouse DB**  instance with docker?

Answer (score 9):

## ClickHouse setup

This is a setup guide for deploying **[ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.tech/)**  with docker on remote servers.

## Installation

You have to have docker preinstalled on your remote system.

### Server

Run the following command:

```
$ docker run -d --name some-clickhouse-server -p 8123:8123 --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 --volume=$HOME/some_clickhouse_database:/var/lib/clickhouse yandex/clickhouse-server
```

ClickHouse server uses port *8123* as the default port but you can uses any other open port but remember to expose the port to the external  network.  The server comes with a default users with no password.

### Client

Run the following command in the server to connect to the clickhouse server with the default user.

```
$ docker run -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server
```

## Configuration

Open the clickhouse server docker container

```
$ docker exec -it some-clickhouse-server bash
```

### 1.  Enable SQL-driven access control and account management for the  `default`  user.

In the clickhouse server docker container:

`$ cd etc/clickhouse-server`

Comment out the  following line in **user.xml** file to enable access control:

```
<access_management>1</access_management>
```

**Note** that this operation is unsafe and after finishing you work, you should change the access control to :

```
<access_management>0</access_management>
```

### 2. Listening to other networks:

In the `etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml` comment out `<listen_host>::</listen_host>` to allow remote connections.
You should see the port is open in the systems network:

```
root@myvm:~# lsof -i :8123
COMMAND       PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 1141768 root    4u  IPv6 53989091      0t0  TCP *:8123 (LISTEN)
```

## Creating a DB with users

In this part we create a simple database and a users. Then we *Grant privileges* of the database to that user.

There are two types of synchronization and they can complement each other:

### 1. [Creating](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/user/) an users

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS user1 IDENTIFIED WITH PLAINTEXT_PASSWORD BY 'pass1'
```

You can check the users with the `SHOW USERS` command.

### 2. [Creating](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/database/) a database

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1
```

You can check the databases with the `SHOW DATABASES` command.

### 3. [Grant](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/grant/) database privileges to the user

You can grant limited privileges or all privileges to a users.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO user1
```

### 4. Connect with the new users to the database

Now we can connect to the server with the created account.

```
$ docker run -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server -u user1 --password pass1
```

Make sure the users has all the permissions and has access to the databases:

```
:) SHOW GRANTS
:) SHOW DATABASES
```

## Creating a Sample Table

Clickhouse supports **[SQL](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/)** .

To create a table:

```
:) USE db1
```

```
:) CREATE TABLE names (
 id UInt64,
 name String,
 created DateTime
 ) ENGINE = MergeTree()
 PRIMARY KEY id
 ORDER BY id;
```

```
:) SHOW TABLES
```

There you have it. You can connect to the databases from other networks with the clickhouse-client and your user/password.

Answer (score 0):

Please clone this project and follow the instructions as per the README.md file. After running the docker compose you will have 2 shards and 2 replica setup of clickhouse.

https://github.com/vinitk95/clickhouse-cluster.git